# How can $\Phi(x)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\ln(|x|)$ be a solution of Laplace equation?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

In the book of Evans (PDE), page 22, they say that $$\Phi(\boldsymbol x)=-\frac{1}{2\pi}\log|\boldsymbol x|$$
is a solution of $\Delta u=0$ in $\mathbb R^2$. How is this possible ? $$\Phi(x,y)=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\ln(x^2+y^2),$$

and thus $$\Delta \Phi(x,y)=-\frac{1}{4\pi}\left(\frac{2x}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{2y}{x^2+y^2}\right)\neq 0.$$

Where is the problem here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you (correctly) calculated $\partial_x\Phi+\partial_y\Phi$ instead of $\Delta\Phi=\partial^2_x\Phi+\partial^2_y\Phi$.

Comment: haha, that's indeed an excellent remark :) (I was stuck for nothing...) Thanks a lot

Comment: Never mind - happens all the time. ;-)